# In unix (Ubuntu) How do I run a service, or application as a certain user?

Tags: ubuntu, unix

I'm told I should run my Rails app as the user `www-data`, how do I do that? How can I also run say Nginx, and other services as certain users? What is the best practice for this?

Comment: Ubuntu is not a Unix.

Comment: @Recursion: Merely a technicality. All it lacks is the certification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many programs, particularly those intended to be run as daemons, will have a command line flag for which user to run as. These are particularly important for applications which expect to use 'privileged' ports -- under 1024 -- as only root can open listen sockets there. Most such apps will start as root, read the configs, open sockets, then setuid() to a restricted user.

Other programs -- mainly ones that don't need low-numbered ports -- can just be run via an 'su' call in their startup script.

Answer (score 1):

The sudo command also does that; checkout its man page.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, suexec (switch user exec), is what you are looking for.

ubuntu doc
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/suexec.8.html

apache doc
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/suexec.html